# How do I open the "inspect element" panel when right click context menu is disabled on a page?

Tags: google-chrome

There is a web page which disabled mouse right click. When I right click on an element on that page with mouse nothing happens. I wanted to open the "inspect element" panel to have a look at the HTML code of some part of the page; but I couldn't since right click was disabled.

Is there any other way of opening this panel?

*(Google Chrome version: 24.0.1312.57 m)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution would be to disable Javascript using one of many available plugins.

Another is to simply open developer tools and navigate to that element. There are few ways to do it:

- press <kbd>F12</kbd>
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- Menu → Tools → Developer tools

Answer (score 2):

You can disable JavaScript in the browser, or only on that site using an extension like [NotScripts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/notscripts/odjhifogjcknibkahlpidmdajjpkkcfn). You can also use extensions such as [Allow Right-Click](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-right-click/hompjdfbfmmmgflfjdlnkohcplmboaeo), [Allow RightClick](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-rightclick/odgmhaimkkjbnpmnpbgemphpcedcbbfd), [Enable Right Click](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-right-click/dcjhdaiolbgldmmfggnlbmjcifkmhohi) and so on.

Any such browser/JavaScript-based mouse button blocking or context menu hijacking is never a great idea in any case, since it can be easily circumvented and ultimately, users are in charge of their browsers on their systems, and any misguided attempts to restrict functionality will only turn them off.

Answer (score -1):

There wouldn't be many ways to do it if the administrator had blocked access to inspect element. One method i'm familiar with is removing Java-script or copying the source code then modifying it to run inspect element only if there is valid info on that site.

Comment: This question is over 6 years old. Please remember to make sure you are adding useful answers to questions, especially for old questions that already have answers. Also, not all sites will work the same way locally, as you could run into XSS issues or data is necessary that won't be accessed when run locally. This approach likely causes more problems than it solves, without a lot of extra work.  The accepted answer gives 3 options that work without modifying the code and running it locally, and avoids all the problems I've stated.

Answer (score -3):

there is now way to do it if the administrator blocked it. I work as a superintendent at google. Its virtually impossible